# Let $f$ be an affine transformation. If $f^2$ has a fixed point, how do I proof that $f$ have fixed points?

Tags: affine-geometry, fixed-points

I tried using the definition of affine transformation, where I got the following:

$f^2(X) = f(f(X)) = C + Mf(X) = C + M(C + MX) = (I + M)C + M^2X = X \Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(I+M)C = 0 \\
M^2=1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$

There, I get that either $C=0$ or $M=-I$.

If $C=0$, then $f(X) = MX$, so $M = I$, and if $M = -I$, $f(X) = C - X$, so $C=2X$. But I'm not so sure that what I wrote is a good proof (or correct, in that regard). How do I do it, then?

It doesn't need to be an unique fixed point. The result says that there is "at least" one fixed point.

P.S.: How do I do it if instead of having $f^2$ I have $f^n$, for $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: I don't agree with the conditions you are imposing on $M$ and $C$. These whould be the conditions in order for $f$ to be an involution, id est for $f\circ f=id$, id est for the identity $f(f(x))=x$ to hold *for all* $x$. However, having a fixed point means that *there is* some $u$ such that $f(f(u))=u$. Therefore you have weaker hypothesis and weaker thesis.

Comment: Also, unless you are considering a trasformation $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, you are not allowed to claim that $Av=0$ implies $A=0$ or $v=0$, and by a length.

Comment: I am considering the transformation $\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$. My apologies for not clarifying.

Comment: So I have to find the $X$ rather than imposing conditions to $M$ and $C$? Or is there an easier way to prove it?

Comment: In principle, you have to find conditions on $M$ and $C$ so that some $X$ exists for $f^2$, and see if they imply tat some $X$ (not necessarily the same) exists for $f$.

Comment: I've tried to keep going with the equation and I ended with $C = (I+M)^{-1}(I-M^2)X$ (let's suppose that $det(I+M)\neq0$). So when I do $f(X) = C + MX = (I+M)^{-1}(I-M^2)X + MX$ and I try to find $M$ so $f(X) = X$ I end up with $0=0$. So does that mean that for any $M$ such as $det(I+M)\neq 0$ $f(X) = X$?

Comment: Here are my calculations: $((I+M)^{-1}(I-M^2) + M)X = X \Rightarrow (I+M)^{-1}(I-M^2) + M = I \Rightarrow I-M^2+(I+M)M = I+M \Rightarrow I-M^2+M+M^2 = I + M \Rightarrow 0=0$.

Comment: Nevermind, I can do it by reduction ad absurdum i could suppose that $f(X)\neq X$, do all of the operations above and reach the conclusion that $0\neq0$, which is a contradiction.